# Why is AJAX returning Id with value 0 from external list

Tags: ajax, wcf, rest, azure, sharepoint

I am developing a Sharepoint-hosted app on my developer site with Azure database using WCF service. The service is hosted on Azure which i imported on my SharePoint-hosted app. I was able to fetch the database on azure. However, each items are returned with an Id of 0, which i suspect is the cause where i was unable to update or delete an when using /Items/GetItemById(item id). Adding new items works just fine. The table has 4 columns (NoteID (primary key, is identity), Title, Description, Creation). I hope somebody can explain this. TIA

My AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyListName')/items,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function (key, val) {
            console.log(val);
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Failed to get customer");
    }
});
```

Below is the result:

> value: Array[9]
>
> 0: Object
>
> BdcIdentity: "**bg40001300"
>   Creation: "2016-1-30 14:56:59"
>   Description: "Lunch with the boss"
>   FileSystemObjectType: 0
>   Id: 0
>   NoteID: 1
>   Title: "Lunch"
>   ...
>   odata.type: "SP.Data.NotesListItem"
>   __proto**: Object
>
> 1: Object
>
> BdcIdentity: "**bg40002300"
>   Creation: "2016-2-29 10:06:35"
>   Description: "Send project propossal."
>   FileSystemObjectType: 0
>   Id: 0
>   NoteID: 2
>   Title: "Project Proposal"
>   ...
>   odata.type: "SP.Data.NotesListItem"
>   __proto**: Object
>
> 2: Object
>
> BdcIdentity: "**bg40003300"
>   Creation: null
>   Description: "Some description."
>   FileSystemObjectType: 0
>   Id: 0
>   NoteID: 3
>   Title: "Some title"
>   ...
>   odata.type: "SP.Data.NotesListItem"
>   __proto**: Object
>
> 3: Object
>   4: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

**/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyListName')/GetItemByStringId('BdcIdentity')**

instead of

**/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyListName')/Items/GetItemById(item id)**

to get a list item.

Comment: tried your suggestion and it works. I can now update and delete items. I knew it the BdcIdentity could be use but never tried digging on it. You saved the day. Many thanks!